# PDF generated from JAVA is damaged using Jasper Reports

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using `iReport Designer 4.7` to create `.jrxml`. Its a very simle `.jrxml` which displays parameters passsed
from JAVA. The test pdf gets generated from iReport Designer and I can view it using Adobe Reader.

Now, Here is the java code

I am calling `createReport(String reportName, Map params)` from Servlet.
The parameters are set from Servlet. There will be always parameters passed.

```
public void generateReport(String fileName, String outFileName, Map paramerterMap,
            String reportFormat) throws JRException{

    String reportSource = "C:\\jrxml\\" + fileName;
    String outFile = null;
    downloadPath = "C:\\pdfs\\";

    outFile = downloadPath + outFileName;
            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportSource, paramerterMap);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING,"UTF-8");
                    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outFile);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);

                    exporter.exportReport();
}

public Boolean createReport(String reportName, Map params) {
    try {
        String jrFile = reportName + ".jasper";
        String outFileName = String.valueOf(7884);
        outFileName += "_" + reportName + ".pdf";
        generateReport(jrFile, outFileName, params, ".pdf");
        return true;
    }  catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("ReportManager--generateReport--JRException: " + e);
                    return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("ReportManager--generateReport--Exception: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using same set of `.jar` which iReport Designer used.
(In fact I have copied `.jar` files from iReport installation directory)

**Problem: The pdf generated using JAVA code is broken.**
When I try to open PDF at created location, The Adobe reader says :

> Adobe Reader could not open 'test.pdf' because it is either not a
>   supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example,
>   it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

[image]

EDIT: I do not get any exception and the generated file size is around 5 KB.

EDIT2: Adding JRXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Certificate" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7367a6fb-f8da-4ba3-b90d-319807f92789">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="27" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="b72c0bad-3935-40ba-8d6d-3993cb5122d2" key="textField" x="413" y="0" width="140" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="141" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="cbaae0d4-53da-420e-8efa-7f4fcc6900f0" key="name" x="0" y="10" width="530" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you share the PDF so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: I would like yo but, SO does not allow attachment any other image.

Comment: Is there any exception? Has the generated file content, or does it have a size of 0 Byte?

Comment: @Ralph: No, There is no exception and file has content and its size is 5KB

Comment: could you post your JRXML please.

Answer (score 1):

Hardik,

I see 2-3 things over here

1) Your outfile name in generateReport always comes as "c:\pdfs"+ NULL.
( I wonder why test.pdf is still created )

2) What does `gujarati` object contains parameters for reports??

**EDIT**

3) Just asking why keep two seperate function for report generation?
In my opinion you could achieve the objective with single function `createReport`.!

**EDIT : 2**

I think this link might offer some help : http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/faq.html?group_id=252#FAQ29

Comment: I have edited the question. I have pasted code excerpt. So, Now I have removed gujarati object part.  Can we chat ?

Comment: yeah sure we can.. but i dont know how to start it on SO, never done before :(